# sum of multiplying two matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrix `e`:

```
e =

 1     1     1     2     3
 1     3     3     2     2
 1     1     1     1     1
```

and I have another matrix that is 3-dimensions:

```
z=cat(3,z1,z2,z3)
```

`z1`, `z2` and `z3` are something like:

```
z1 =

 2     3     4     0     6
 6     7     8     9     0
 2     3     4     5     6

z2 =

 4     6     7     8     9
 2     3     4     5     0
 1     1     0     0     0

z3 =

 4     4     6     7     0
 0     0     9     8     1
 1     1     3     1     1
```

I want to calculate the sum of the result of multiplying `e` by `z` such that in every element of `e` that is `1`, `e` multiply to `z1` and every element of matrix `e` that is `2`, `e` multiply to `z2` and also in every element of matrix `e` that is `3`, `e` multiply to `z3`.

Thus, I want the result matrix:

```
result = [ 2 3 4 8 0;
           6 0 9 5 0; 
           2 3 4 5 6]
```

Then, sum of the elements of the matrix, i.e. `sum(sum(result))`.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Welcome to SO. The desired behavior here is that people need to show their effort in terms of code and research before asking a question. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Thank you. If you think that, you can give me some clue no code. thank you any way.

Comment: my wrong code is something like that: `z1(find(e==1)).*find(e==1)+z2(find(e==2)).*find(e==2)+z3(find(e==3)).*find(e==3)`.  but I got error **Matrix dimensions must agree**.

Comment: So, what's the expected output for the given sample data?

Comment: I try to get the result matrix like that:  `result =

    [ 2     3     4     8     0;
     6     0     9     5     0;
     2     3     4     5     6]` and then sum of the elements of this matrix. it means `sum(sum(result))
`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
result = sum(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@eq,e,permute(1:3,[1 3 2])),z),3)
```

If you want to get `sum(sum(result))` directly -

```
final_result = reshape(bsxfun(@eq,e,permute(1:3,[1 3 2])),1,[])*z(:)
```

Comment: @user196345 Sure, no worries!